# Convert html special characters into numeric codes with PHP

Tags: php, html, special-characters, html-entities

Let's say I have a *string*
`$a = "à"`.
I want to convert it to html entities.

```
$b = htmlentities($a); // &agrave;
```

Instead, I want it to be converted to its numeric version: `"&#224;"`
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `$b = ord($a); //returns 224` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

```
$a = "à";
$b = ord($a); //224
```